# How do you remove the previous and next buttons in mkdocs?

Tags: mkdocs

I am trying to remove the previous and next buttons in mkdocs but I don't want it to be hacky.

I have read the [docs](https://www.mkdocs.org/) and searched the web and haven't found anything other than some GitHub issues.

Remove these buttons!

[image: buttons]

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I would do this using CSS to hide it by adding into the included css. In the material theme it will be:

```css
md-footer__inner { display: none }
```

This should be within the css which is included as `extra_css` in the `mkdocs.yml`.

Comment: For some reason, the CSS rules in `main.css` were overwriting this line that I wrote in extra_css. I had to use `display: none !important;` to overcome that.